# <xsl:if> condition not satisfied still giving output

Tags: xml, xslt

Given  below XML and corresponding XSL code , why are we getting the output when the condition is not satisfied ?

As far as I understand , since there are multiple wonder nodes, it will consider first one and then it sees that condition is false and hence it should not show the output.

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="02-01.xsl"?>

<ancient_wonders>
    <wonder>
        <name language="English">Colossus of Rhodes1</name>
        <name language="Greek">Κολοσσός της Ρόδου1</name>
        <location>Rhodes, Greece</location>
        <height units="feet">107</height>
        <main_image filename="colossus.jpg" w="528" h="349"/>
        <source sectionid="101" newspaperid="21"></source>
    </wonder>

    <wonder>
        <name language="English">Colossus of Rhodes2</name>
        <name language="Greek">Κολοσσός της Ρόδου2</name>
        <location>Rhodes, Greece</location>
        <height units="feet">120</height>
        <main_image filename="colossus.jpg" w="528" h="349"/>
        <source sectionid="103" newspaperid="21"></source>
    </wonder>


</ancient_wonders>
```

**XSLT :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!-- Output Method -->
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- Root Template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
            <body>

                <p><b>Output 1 :</b></p>
                <xsl:if test="ancient_wonders/wonder/height != 107">
                    <p>Height = <xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
                </xsl:if>

                <p><b>Output 2 :</b></p>
                <xsl:if test="ancient_wonders/wonder/height != 107">
                    <p>Height = <xsl:value-of select="ancient_wonders/wonder/height" /></p>
                </xsl:if>

            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output :**

```
Output 1 :

Height = Colossus of Rhodes1 Κολοσσός της Ρόδου1 Rhodes, Greece 107 Colossus of Rhodes2 Κολοσσός της Ρόδου2 Rhodes, Greece 120

Output 2 :

Height = 107
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
ancient_wonders/wonder/height
```

selects both `height` elements in your document. The test:

```
test="ancient_wonders/wonder/height != 107"
```

returns true, because there is at least one node in the compared node-set that satisfies the condition - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans

---

Only the `xsl:value-of` instruction has the anomaly of returning only the value of the first node of the selected node-set; this anomaly was removed in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Just for my info , what does `xsl:value-of` do now in XSLT 2.0 when multiple nodes satisfies the XPATH ?

Comment: It lists them all, separated by a space or by the specified separator.

Comment: I found an [online XSLT 2.0 processor](http://fiddle.frameless.io/) , but for `xsl:value-of` , still it gives first node output only  ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Cpmpare https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq66 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq66/1.

Comment: Thnx for the link. But even [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq66/3) , only first node output is showing ?

Comment: And now? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq66/3 Read about compatibility mode here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards.